# Fastest way to test if two integers differ by 4 or equal to each other

Tags: arduino-uno, c

I'm searching for the fastest way to test if two integers are equal or differ by 4. The integers can be positive, negative and equal to zero. They are between -1000 and 1000 and are exclusively multiples of 4.

The simplest approach to test this should be this:

```
if(x == y || x - y == 4 || x - y == -4)
{
     //do something...
}
```

But since I want to do this 4 times inside of a interrupt sub routine I wanted to know if there is a faster way to do this.

Comment: The fastest way could depend on the frequencies of the cases.  You could try using some bit operations to take the absolute value, divide it by 4 (>>2) and then branch on it being one or less.

Comment: A search to "the fastest way" would never give you a solid result. You could use a faster microcontroller almost endlessly attempt to optimalize. Check the requirements you need rather than searching for "the best"

Comment: Maybe you can do something fancy with the bit patterns. If you XOR them, it might give the difference between your value and the other. It can then be 0b00000000 or 0b00000100 but why steps of 4 if 4 more or less doesn't matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to do the same comparison 4 times you can just put the result into a boolean variable.

```
boolean b = (x == y || x - y == 4 || x - y == -4)

if( b )
{
     //do something...
}
```

If you are talking about optimizing the actual code, I shouldn't worry about it. The compiler is already pretty good at this. Here is the assembler code for it.

```
void test(int x, int y)
{
    if(x == y || x - y == 4 || x - y == -4)
  a8:   86 17           cp  r24, r22
  aa:   97 07           cpc r25, r23
  ac:   39 f0           breq    .+14        ; 0xbc <_Z4testii+0x14>
  ae:   86 1b           sub r24, r22
  b0:   97 0b           sbc r25, r23
  b2:   84 30           cpi r24, 0x04   ; 4
  b4:   91 05           cpc r25, r1
  b6:   11 f0           breq    .+4         ; 0xbc <_Z4testii+0x14>
  b8:   04 96           adiw    r24, 0x04   ; 4
  ba:   09 f4           brne    .+2         ; 0xbe <_Z4testii+0x16>
    {
        asm ("wdr");
  bc:   a8 95           wdr
  be:   08 95           ret
```

first it compare the two values x and y. Then is subtract y from x and compares it with 4. After that it gets the subtracted value from the previous step; adds 4; and check if it is `0`.

**EDIT**

As to Dave X's suggestion; using `if(abs(x-y)<=4)`

```
void test(int x, int y)
{
    if(abs(x-y)<=4)
  a8:   86 1b           sub r24, r22
  aa:   97 0b           sbc r25, r23
  ac:   04 96           adiw    r24, 0x04   ; 4
  ae:   09 97           sbiw    r24, 0x09   ; 9
  b0:   08 f4           brcc    .+2         ; 0xb4 <_Z4testii+0xc>
    {
         asm("wdr");
  b2:   a8 95           wdr
  b4:   08 95           ret
```

So half the number of instructions needed. But as Paul said, this might not the fastest. This code always takes 5 instructions, while the previous code will only take 3 instructions if `x==y`. So if 90% of the time x==y, the previous code will be faster 90% of the time.

As to the assembler code, you can see how clever the compiler is. It first subtracts y from x. Then it adds 4. If `-4 <= x-y < 0` the carry bit is set. Then it subtracts 9 (so it's like `(x-y)-5` because of the previous `+4`). If `0<= x-y <= 4` the carry bit is set. It then check if the carry bits is set by either of the last to instructions. Pretty clever.

Comment: (I just learned how to view the assembly code with an avrdump -S on the .elf file).   Maybe `if(abs(x-y)<=4)` would be a quicker, equivalent test.  It is interesting to see how the compiler optimizes that.

Comment: @DaveX We have a winner. I did't think that one would be faster.

Comment: `avr-objdump` has the `-C` option to demangle C++ symbols. It makes nicer looking assembly listings.

Answer (score 2):

> test if two integers are equal or differ by 4

And

> are exclusively multiples of 4.

That would mean that when a=20, b should be 16, 20 or 24. (But can't be 17, 18, 19, 21, 22 or 23)

But you should check the most unlikely statement first. If it's likely to be well above x+4, check that first, if it's false, it'll just stop.

Ultimately you only have to check if it's less than x=y+4 or higher as x=y-4, this automatically includes x=y.
So checking if it's the same (which might be unlikely, might be redundant. Unless there is a very high chance of that being true.

Comment: "Checking if its less than x = y + 4 or higher as x= y-4"? You might want to clarify

Comment: If it can be either 24, 28 or 32 (with steps of 4) you only have to check <33 and higher as 23> that will automatically include the check if it's 28. But is only valid with the steps of 4 rule